# Insert query for Many to Many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a many to many python web app for a class.  I have a users table joined to trips table with a joiner table called user_trips:

```
USERS

`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
`username` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB


TRIPS
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `destination` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
 `start_date` DATETIME NULL,
 `end_date` DATETIME NULL,
 `plan` TEXT(256) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB


 JOINER TABLE
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `travel_test`.`user_trips` (
 `trips_id` INT NOT NULL,
 `users_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`trips_id`, `users_id`),
```

I feel comfortable with all other entity relationships, but cannot seem to get how to create an insert statement to insert a new trip for a given user in the users table.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: needs editing/formatting

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question.can you explain with samples?

Comment: I'm trying to create a trip planning site.  Each user can have many trips (create individual trips) as well as join others and share in their trips, and therefore, each trip can have any users.  I'm trying to create one single query statement that the route in my server.py can use to do an insert query.   so far, I am only able to run two separate queries to create the trip and then update  joiner table separately like so

Comment: insert into trips (destination, start_date, end_date, plan) values ('Germany', NOW(), NOW(), 'stroll on boulevard')
insert into user_trips (trips_id, users_id) values (1, 1)